# Unable to launch Confluent control center on AKS

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, confluent-platform, confluent-control-center

I am starting my journey on Confluent for Kubernetes and while following their quick start guide
to install Confluent on AKS I was able to get the pods up and running.
https://docs.confluent.io/operator/current/co-quickstart.html

```
confluent-operator-99f7f8dcb-87ll8   1/1     Running   0          7m30s
connect-0                            1/1     Running   2          6m22s
controlcenter-0                      1/1     Running   0          3m
elastic-0                            1/1     Running   4          6m5s
kafka-0                              1/1     Running   0          4m22s
kafka-1                              1/1     Running   0          4m22s
kafka-2                              1/1     Running   0          4m22s
ksqldb-0                             1/1     Running   0          3m1s
schemaregistry-0                     1/1     Running   0          3m
zookeeper-0                          1/1     Running   0          6m23s
zookeeper-1                          1/1     Running   0          6m23s
zookeeper-2                          1/1     Running   0          6m23s
```

running a quick curl on http://localhost:9021 is giving me a html output.

However after enabling web preview on cloud shell and previewing the port 9021 it is giving me a blank white page.

Am I doing anything wrong? How do I view http://localhost:9021 on AKS?

Answer (score 1):

```
kubectl port-forward controlcenter-0 9021:9021
```

It is also written in the docs [here](https://docs.confluent.io/operator/current/co-quickstart.html#step-4-view-control-center).

Comment: Hi after port forwarding I am unable to access localhost that is the issue

Comment: @FalconHawk Did you solve this problem? In my case also I am unable to access http://localhost:9021.